# Applescript launching of Spotlight?

Tags: applescript, spotlight

I tried to use the following to open the Spotlight search box:

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke " " using {command down}
end tell
```

It simply tries to issue command-space. It does work, but if I save the script as an Application and run it, the Spotlight window shows up and then promptly disappears afterwards.

Why does this happen and what can I do to keep the Spotlight window open?

Alternatively: **How do I open the Spotlight search box using Applescript?**

Answer (score 2):

Your script opens the Spotlight *menu*. The keyboard shortcut for opening the Spotlight *window* is <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>...

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke space using {command down, option down}
```

**UPDATE:** Given your revised answer, I have composed a little script that should do what you want...

```
set the searchText to the text returned of (display dialog "Enter the name of an item you wish to search for in Spotlight:" default answer "")
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke space using {command down}
    keystroke the searchText
    --[1]
end tell
```

You can do one of the following things at [1]:

- Open the top hit:

  ```
  keystroke return using {command down}
  ```
- Move the selection to the first item in the next category:

  ```
  keystroke (ASCII character 31) using {command down} --down arrow
  ```
- Move the selection to the first item in the previous category:

  ```
  keystroke (ASCII character 30) using {command down} --up arrow
  ```
- Move the selection to the first item in the whole menu:

  ```
  keystroke (ASCII character 31) using {control down}
  ```
- Move the selection to the last item in the whole menu:

  ```
  keystroke (ASCII character 30) using {control down}
  ```

Comment: Okay. Wrong terminology. I'm looking for the script to open the _menu_.

Comment: Does this mean that it is not possible to keep the Spotlight search box open with Applescript? What I'm looking for is not to have another  window. I want to open the Spotlight search box and have the cursor in the search box, ready for user input.

Comment: As far as I know you can't keep the Spotlight window open with Applescript. I'm sorry. Have you tried my script yet?

Comment: For me it works: osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke space using {command down}
'

Answer (score 0):

Simple add a delay.

```
     tell application "System Events"
         keystroke " " using {command down}
         delay 5
         delay 5
     end tell
```

Or to foolproof this: